# How can I undelete a revision that I deleted with "php deleteRevision.php"

Tags: mediawiki

So i was playing around with my User: page on my mediawiki setup and i wanted to clean up the revision history of thousands of revisions of me playing around. I learned about [deleteRevision.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteRevision.php) and testing it on one revision and being happy with how it worked i used the following javascript in Chrome's Developer Console,

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.mw-changeslist-date')
var output = ""
for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++)
{
    output += links[i].href+"\r\n"
}
console.log(output)
```

copied the console log into Notepad++ and did a fine and replace on the the constant url replacing it with a space so when i added the script file to the front it would

```
php deleteRevision.php id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id id
```

and then in putty I ran the script, only remembering after that I wanted all but 1 deleted *facepalm* and i didn't do a database update prior *facedesk*. now when i go to my User: page i get

> The revision #0 of the page named "User:admean" does not exist.
>
> This is usually caused by following an outdated history link to a page that has been deleted. Details can be found in the deletion log.

i tried running `php undelete.php User:admean` and while it says it was successful I get the same error. i know that the data does still exist as under the details for deleteRevision.php it says

> deleteRevision.php file is a maintenance script to delete one or more revisions **by moving them to the archive table**.

and checking the table i see a bunch of records that the total number is the number of revisions i deleted. though i wouldn't know where to clone the data to.

i've also tried Special:Undelete but no matter how many or little revisions i select i get the message

> Undelete failed:
>   Invalid or missing revision.
>
> You may have a bad link, or the revision may have been restored or removed from the archive.

which makes no sense because the number of records in the archive table matches to the number of revisions i have deleted and there is a few thousand

So how can I undelete a revision that I deleted with `php deleteRevision.php`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to find out my tables: (assuming you used MySQL like I did)

```
$ mysqlcheck -a -A -u username -p'password' --verbose
```

and it gave me a list of table names like:

```
wiki.archive                                   OK
wiki.page                                      OK
```

then I used

```
$  mysql -u username -p'password' --verbose
```

and it gave me some text and a prompt:

> mysql>

so I told it a explain command:

```
mysql> explain wiki.page ;

--------------
explain wiki.page
--------------

+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| page_id            | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page_namespace     | int(11)             | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| page_title         | varchar(255)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| page_restrictions  | tinyblob            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| page_is_redirect   | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| page_is_new        | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| page_random        | double unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| page_touched       | char(14)            | NO   |     |         |                |
| page_latest        | int(8) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| page_len           | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| page_content_model | varbinary(32)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page_links_updated | varbinary(14)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| page_lang          | varbinary(35)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
13 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

or:

```
mysql> explain wiki.revision ;

--------------
explain wiki.revision
--------------

+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rev_id             | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| rev_page           | int(8) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| rev_comment        | varbinary(767)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rev_user           | int(5) unsigned     | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| rev_user_text      | varchar(255)        | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| rev_timestamp      | char(14)            | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| rev_minor_edit     | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| rev_deleted        | tinyint(1) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| rev_text_id        | int(8) unsigned     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| rev_parent_id      | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rev_len            | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rev_sha1           | varbinary(32)       | NO   |     |         |                |
| rev_content_format | varbinary(64)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rev_content_model  | varbinary(32)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

14 rows in set (0.01 sec)

That told me the columns of the table so I could use them in a select command.
like:

```
mysql>  select * from vistapedia.revision where rev_id = 123456 ;
```

I hope this helps.